# Is it possible to reset the console output color just using SetConsoleTextAttribute() on windows?

Tags: c, windows, console

I'm looking for a way to use SetConsoleTextAttribute() to reset the output color of the windows console, doing what  `\033[0m` does on Mac and Linux. Is there any way of doing this? I'm looking to avoid external libraries and instead just use windows.h

Comment: [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute) certainly seems to suggest it is possible. 
 But it also recommends using [Console Virtual Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) escape sequences instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a reset function, you just have to save the attributes when your program starts.

> To determine the current color attributes of a screen buffer, call the GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo function.

cmd.exe works the same way:

```
color 09
cmd /k
color&rem still blue because this instance started blue
exit
color&rem restored now
```

Also, don't forget to use `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` to restore the color on Ctrl+C.